# Spock Testing: Too few invocation

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spock

I am writing Spock test for a Service class whose method calls another method in a Dao class  in a spring boot application.  However, I am getting:

```
 Too few invocations for:
 1 * dao.getAddressFromSomewhere("me")   (0 invocations)
 Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):
 None
```

Below is the source code and the testing code, can someone please let me know what I did wrong?  It seems that the dao mock didn't get invoked and return "USA" at all.  I have done some research online and can't find what I did wrong.

```
@Service
public class ServiceClass 
{
    @Autowired
    private DaoClass dao;

    public String getAddress(String name) {         
        return dao.getAddressFromSomewhere(name);
    }
}

@Component
public class DaoClass {
     public String getAddressFromSomewhere(String name) {
     // get address from DB
     ......
     }
}
```

And here is my Spock testing code:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@Import(ServiceClass.class)
public class Test extends Specification {

@Autowired
private DaoClass dao;
@Autowired
private ServiceClass service;

@TestConfiguration
static class MockConfig {
    def detachedMockFactory = new DetachedMockFactory()
    @Bean
    DaoClass dao() {
        return detachedMockFactory.Mock(DaoClass)
    }
}

def "Test Success Senario"() {                     
    given: "dao"
          dao.getAddressFromSomewhere("me") >> "USA";

    when: "call service "
       def actualResponse = service.getAddress("me");

    then: "dao should be invoked with given response"
       1 * dao.getAddressFromSomewhere("me")
       actualResponse == "USA"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By writing `1 * dao.getAddressFromSomewhere("me")` in `then:` block you just override the interaction `dao.getAddressFromSomewhere("me") >> "USA"` in your `given:` block. And by not declaring the returning value through `>>` you just tell the mock to return `null`. You can check the interactions order with the [Spock doc](http://There%20is%20one%20exception%20to%20this%20rule:%20Interactions%20declared%20in%20a%20then:%20block%20are%20matched%20against%20before%20any%20other%20interactions.%20This%20allows%20to%20override%20interactions%20declared%20in,%20say,%20a%20setup%20method%20with%20interactions%20declared%20in%20a%20then:%20block.):

> ...Interactions declared in a then: block are matched against before any other interactions. This allows to override interactions declared in, say, a setup method with interactions declared in a then: block.

You can rewrite your example in a couple of ways:

1. Declare your interaction in `given:` block

```
def "Test Success Senario"() {
    given: "dao"
    1 * dao.getAddressFromSomewhere("me") >> "USA"

    when: "call service "
    def actualResponse = service.getAddress("me")

    then: "dao should be invoked with given response"
    actualResponse == "USA"
}
```

2. Declare your interaction in `then:` block:

```
def "Test Success Senario"() {
    when: "call service "
    def actualResponse = service.getAddress("me")

    then: "dao should be invoked with given response"
    1 * dao.getAddressFromSomewhere("me") >> "USA"
    actualResponse == "USA"
}
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but maybe you could also have quoted the actually crucial bit of information from the [Spock documentation](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3-RC1/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing) saying: _"When mocking and stubbing the **same method call**, they have to happen in the **same interaction.** In particular, (...) Mockito-style splitting of stubbing and mocking into two separate statements will **not** work"_

Comment: @kriegaex  and Dmitry Khamitov .  Thank you for the response.  However I tried the option #1 above, but the assertion failed on actualResponse == "USA".  I added logs in the actual service method, it showed that the correct input was passed to the Dao method, but the Dao method returned null, rather than the set value "USA".  For option #2, still got the "too few invocation" error

Comment: @jlp it's very strange. Maybe 1) `@Autowired` is missing now on your `DaoClass dao` (commented out?) or 2) `@TestConfiguration` annotation is missing now (commented out?) and you imported not just `ServiceClass` but also `DaoClass` is picked up somehow (`@Import([ServiceClass, DaoClass])`?). The former causes interactions configured on field `dao` not assigned (autowired) to the detached mock. The latter just ignores your test configuration and uses some other instance of `DaoClass`

Comment: @Dmitry Khamitov   I changed something back and forth and it suddenly worked,  Didn't miss Autowired  or TestConfiguration or Import.  not sure what has happened.  I will accept the answer.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Nitpick: For option 2 when you say "Declare your interaction in `when:` block:", it should say "...`then:` block"