# Too few invocations unit testing with Spock

Tags: unit-testing, gradle, groovy, mocking, spock

First time user of Spock (with limited knowledge of Groovy to boot) and I suspect I am hitting the ["one giant gotcha"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53281900/336752) with Spock:

> Mocking and stubbing of the same method call has to happen in the same interaction.

But I can't quite see how my example matches other questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53267791/spock-mocked-classs-method-is-not-being-matched), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841668/spock-mock-returns-wrong-value), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54489759/spock-testing-too-few-invocation) as examples) – all those involve methods which return a value, where the method in question is mocked in the `given` code then verified in the `then`. My code is verifying `void` methods.

This is the code I am trying to test:

```
package com.company

import app.cash.licensee.LicenseeExtension
import app.cash.licensee.LicenseePlugin
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project

class ThirdPartyLicensesCheckPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    @Override
    void apply(final Project project) {
        project.pluginManager.apply(LicenseePlugin)

        def licenseeExtension = project.extensions.findByType(LicenseeExtension)
        project.pluginManager.withPlugin("app.cash.licensee") {
            licenseeExtension.ignoreDependencies("com.company", "common-utils") {
                because "internal project"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to verify that the Licensee plugin is applied and configured correctly.

This is my test code:

```
package com.company

import app.cash.licensee.LicenseeExtension
import app.cash.licensee.LicenseePlugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionContainer
import org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginManager
import spock.lang.Specification

class ThirdPartyLicensesCheckPluginTest extends Specification {

    private ThirdPartyLicensesCheckPlugin plugin

    // Class dependencies

    // Mocks for tests
    private Project project
    private PluginManager pluginManager
    private LicenseeExtension licenseeExtension

    def setup() {
        plugin = new ThirdPartyLicensesCheckPlugin()
        project = Mock(Project)
        pluginManager = Mock(PluginManager)
        project.pluginManager >> pluginManager

        licenseeExtension = Mock(LicenseeExtension)
        project.extensions >> Mock(ExtensionContainer) {
            findByType(LicenseeExtension) >> licenseeExtension
        }
    }

    def "the cashapp/licensee plugin is applied to the project"() {
        given: "a Gradle project"

        when: "this plugin is applied"
        plugin.apply(project)

        then: "the cashapp/licensee plugin is applied"
        1 * pluginManager.apply(LicenseePlugin)
        1 * pluginManager.withPlugin("app.cash.licensee", _)
        1 * licenseeExtension.ignoreDependencies("com.company", "common-utils") { because("internal project")}
    }
}
```

The failure I am getting is:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * licenseeExtension.ignoreDependencies("com.company", "common-utils") { because("internal project")}   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None
```

I tried to verify the action parameter at the same time as the `withPlugin` check, as so:

```
package com.company

import app.cash.licensee.LicenseeExtension
import app.cash.licensee.LicenseePlugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionContainer
import org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginManager
import spock.lang.Specification

class ThirdPartyLicensesCheckPluginTest extends Specification {

    private ThirdPartyLicensesCheckPlugin plugin

    // Class dependencies

    // Mocks for tests
    private Project project
    private PluginManager pluginManager
    private LicenseeExtension licenseeExtension

    def setup() {
        plugin = new ThirdPartyLicensesCheckPlugin()
        project = Mock(Project)
        pluginManager = Mock(PluginManager)
        project.pluginManager >> pluginManager

        licenseeExtension = Mock(LicenseeExtension)
        project.extensions >> Mock(ExtensionContainer) {
            findByType(LicenseeExtension) >> licenseeExtension
        }
    }

    def "the cashapp/licensee plugin is applied to the project"() {
        given: "a Gradle project"

        when: "this plugin is applied"
        plugin.apply(project)

        then: "the cashapp/licensee plugin is applied"
        1 * pluginManager.apply(LicenseePlugin)
        1 * pluginManager.withPlugin("app.cash.licensee") {
            licenseeExtension.ignoreDependencies("wrong.group", "incorrect-project") { because("the wrong reason")}
        }
    }
}
```

But this always passed, even though the verification is wrong.

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/testing_gradle_plugins.html#functional-tests instead of attempting to mock all of gradle?

Comment: This is certainly an option although coming from a Java, JUnit, Mockito world, I would expect to be able to test the code with unit tests. While the code is straightforward in the example, I intend to add slightly more logic to it which would benefit from unit testing.

Comment: Unit tests are shown in the same link. As soon as you are having to mock gradle, I'd say that was an integration test

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @tim_yates that you probably want to use an integration test, your problem is that you are not invoking the closure.

Here is a simplified version:

```
import spock.lang.*

class ASpec extends Specification {
  def "hello world"() {
      given:
      List listMock = Mock()
      PluginContainer pluginContainer = Mock()
      
      when:
      pluginContainer.withPlugin('123') {
          listMock.add(42)
      }    
      then: 
      1 * pluginContainer.withPlugin('123', _) >> { it[1].call() }
      1 * listMock.add(42)
  }
}

interface PluginContainer {
    withPlugin(String id, Closure closure)
}
```

[Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_3_0&codez=eJyFkMFqwzAQRO_6iiGX2CEInPZUaKDk2kAgx1KKkGR7qSoZSakLwf9eq7aJcQvdg5aRtG-GpY_G-YjQOPnOjbAV3zAmjQgBT-dGS-ivqK0KSIJKkiKSs7gyQOkSq1ob49A6b9Qqy3_uU1X0qe3DKJ4pRJj-OPYmeERqWT4-nsylIntwNgqy2qNZ6MX3sbX1Db-Y4C3FeqBm62J3t76lSjXl4EKp7H43cbsZPCb4JAps_nXY4i3Hfo8rKL4Ur1wKY_pldDPEH7Yd6xgjG7UvhdS_FjGEnlmdoydbgdQWB-PCxWvIoec96RsAT4d5)

You can't assert that closures are passed like this, they are not simple values.

```
1 * licenseeExtension.ignoreDependencies("com.company", "common-utils") { because("internal project") }
```

You need to mock it, for example like this:

```
import spock.lang.*

class ASpec extends Specification {
  def "hello world"() {
      given:
      Reason reasonMock = Mock()
      PluginContainer pluginContainer = Mock()
      
      when:
      pluginContainer.withPlugin('123') {
          because("The answer is 42")
      }    
      then: 
      1 * pluginContainer.withPlugin('123', _) >> { reasonMock.with(it[1]) }
      1 * reasonMock.because("The answer is 42")
  }
}

interface PluginContainer {
    withPlugin(String id, Closure closure)
}

interface Reason {
    void because(String reason)
}
```

[Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_3_0&codez=eJyFUcFKxDAQvecrhl42WZZCV0-CC7JnQVxvIhLTaTsYk5KkW2Hpv9u0XbdW0Lk8Xnjz3syEPmrrAvjaqvdUS1Oma8aUlt7D3aFGBfgZ0OQeIqGClAxkDZwYQI4FJBVqbaG1TucJF8N7rJKOaG4m8ojS9z1ugPs-CG4hAheT4EE3JZm9NUGSQQf1gi_kE7TVJWLRkbYUqtGVr7Lt1eoyWaw3VLLxyJOnCkEa3_YZ5OF6m5wjullOiDlnksH637ANvArY7eA0W3kQcQrP2YuAbmY2k_w9Vsc6xsgEdIVU-Otm436zUQ7BkSmB8g3stfWNQ1Ajip9O0_eMBkdL-fd9JotxxNj1BQFjqm4)

The line `1 * pluginContainer.withPlugin('123', _) >> { reasonMock.with(it[1]) }` will invoke the closure, with the `reasonMock` set as `delegate`.